# Android - Падает приложение при загрузке изображений

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Доброго времени суток. При загрузке изображений и вставке их в LinearLayout временами наблюдается падение приложения. LogCat пишет следующее:

```
04-05 18:30:51.269: I/dalvikvm-heap(6419): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.714MB for 2327632-byte allocation
04-05 18:30:52.080: I/dalvikvm-heap(6419): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.941MB for 2327632-byte allocation
04-05 18:30:53.171: I/dalvikvm-heap(6419): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.161MB for 2327632-byte allocation
04-05 18:31:04.212: I/dalvikvm-heap(6419): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.623MB for 8263696-byte allocation
04-05 18:31:06.294: I/dalvikvm-heap(6419): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.269MB for 8263696-byte allocation
04-05 18:31:07.926: I/dalvikvm-heap(6419): Grow heap (frag case) to 27.150MB for 8263696-byte allocation
04-05 18:31:09.767: I/dalvikvm-heap(6419): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.032MB for 8263696-byte allocation
```

Когда доходит до 49000, то приложение падает. Дело, как я понял, в утечке памяти. В таком случае виноват следующий код:

```
String[] screenshots = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
LinearLayout llScreenshots;
// тут еще код + наполнение массива screenshots
llScreenshots = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.entry_screenshots);
for(int i = 0; i < screenshots.length; i++) {
    if(screenshots[i].equals("")) {
        break;
    } else {
        image = new ImageView(EntryPageActivity.this);
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        new DownloadImageTask(image).execute(screenshots[i]);
        llScreenshots.addView(image);
    }
}
//Заканчивается метод onCreate()
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

Как тогда выкручиваться со вставкой изображений в llScreenshots по URL? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте декодировать изображения с помощью экономного конфига. У меня при таком конфиге отлично загружаются ~1500 картинок размером 256х256

```
    BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    op.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; //без альфа-канала.
    op.inSampleSize = 4; //чем больше число (1-16), тем хуже качество, но меньше потребление памяти. Качество 4 практически не заметно на маленьких значках.

    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, op);
```

Comment: большое спасибо, пойду тестить))

Answer (score 2):

не может быть чтобы сразу ВСЕ картинки были нужны вам. От этого нужно избавляться. 
1) попробуй [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview?rq=1) - динамическая подгрузка картинок в другом потоке.

2) на худой конец попробуй увеличить кучу добавив в манифесте .

Comment: это же скриншоты, надо чтоб все видно было, как не все. На экране смартфона их штуки 4 влезет)) а при подгрузке 3 уже хип засорен. Мне интересно, как вк такое сделано? Там ведь и до 100 материалов с изображениями можно смотреть, а heap в порядке, как так?))

Answer (score 0):

Это не утечка памяти, а нехватка хипа.

Посмотрите максимальный размер оного на вашем устройстве

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```

Вот размеры хипа для некоторых устройств (чисто для справки):

Телефоны:

```
HTC Wildfire (2.2.1) = 16MB
HTC Wildfire S (2.3.5) = 20MB
HTC Salsa (2.3.3) = 20MB
HTC Desire (2.3.3) = 32MB
HTC Desire S (2.3.5) = 32MB
Samsung Galaxy S GT-I9000 (2.2) = 48MB
Samsung Galaxy R GT-I9103 (2.3.5) = 64MB
Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360 (2.3.5) = 64MB
Samsung Galaxy Note N7000 (4.1.2) = heapstartsize=8m, heapgrowthlimit=64m, heapsize=256m
Google Galaxy Nexus (4.3) = 8/96/256MB
```

Планшеты:

```
Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 (2.2) = 48MB
Sasmung Galaxy Tab 8.9 GT-P7300 (3.2) = 5/64/288MB
Sasmung Galaxy Tab 10.1 GT-P7500 (3.2) = 5/64/288MB
Acer Iconia A500 (3.2.1) = 5/48/256MB
Kindle Fire HD 7" (4.0.3) = 5/48/256MB
Asus Transformer Prime TF201 (4.1.1) = 5/48/256MB
```

Comment: Так, а что делать-то? Как тогда выкручиваться со вставкой изображений в llScreenshots по URL?

Comment: @Алексей Филиппович, например качество картинки уменьшать. Ниже в ответе @SuperCreeper привёл пример, как можно качество уменьшить. Но это всё равно не панацея. Можно картинки сохранять локально. А отображать по мере необходимости. Ведь вам одновременно не все картинки на экране нужны?

Comment: нужны одновременно все)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, судя по коду, вам не сразу все скриншоты нужны, а по мере прокручивания экрана (ListView).  Если нет сил или желания писать скачивание, обработку и отображение изображений воспользуйтесь готовой библиотекой. [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) например очень даже подойдет. Посмотрите примеры использования у них на сайте.